# Best way to handle different functions based on string value in Android

Tags: java, android, oop

I different values of a string variable viz { type1,type2,type3..}
I have different functions which are called on each string type and this logic is used at multiple places. What is the best way to code this?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a limited number of Strings. In that case you can implement the simple case of checking for each String and calling the appropriate function inside a wrapper function:

```
void function1(int a) {};
void function2(int a) {};
// ... etc

void callFunctionFromString(String s, int a)
{
   if(s.contentEquals("string1"))
        function1(a);
   else if(s.contentEquals("string2"))
        function2(a);
   // .. etc
}
```

Every time you would have had a big if...else statement, just call callFunctionFromString() instead.

But let's assume that you have lots and lots of possible String values. In that case it is more efficient (when you call the function) to create a HashMap of String values to Method calls, like this:

```
interface methodInterface {
    public void callFunction(int a);
}

void function1(int a) {};
void function2(int a) {};
// ... etc

public HashMap<String, methodInterface> stringToFunctionHash = new HashMap<String, methodInterface>();    
void mapStringsToFunctions() throws NoSuchMethodException
{
    stringToFunctionHash.put("string1", new methodInterface(){public void callFunction(int a){function1(a);}});
    stringToFunctionHash.put("string2", new methodInterface(){public void callFunction(int a){function2(a);}});
    // .. etc
}

void callFunctionFromString(String s, int a)
{
    methodInterface m = stringToFunctionHash.get(s);
    if(m != null)
        m.callFunction(a);
}
```

Call mapStringsToFunctions() during your initialisation, and then call callFunctionFromString() as before.

Answer (score 1):

If number od strings is big i advice you use "Chain of responsibility" pattern. This way calling code won't have to decide which function to call but every item in the chain will make decision if it should handle the request. Its also easy to add another handler to the chain.